# CakePHP : Explain ACL

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

I have been looking at CakePHP's ACL tutorials over the last week and it all seems massively complicated. For instance say I had a website that was a simple blog and had the following user types: Admin, Member and Guest. Why could I not have a users table and a groups table (the groups table having a simple CRUD set of columns with 0 or 1 values for each group type)
and then link the users to the groups with a simple ID. And then in the controller just check if the user is logged in or if they are in which group to allow access.

I'm confused about why ACL requires all that additional code and tables, more so why does the ACL table need rebuilding when ever a new controller is created?

If someone could explain some of these questions, it'd be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can use the Auth component without using ACL - see this video: http://tv.cakephp.org/video/andrewperk/2011/01/27/cakephp_auth_component_tutorial_part_1

Comment: Here is another video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M40PgwLqS2M

Answer (score 1):

2-part tutorial on CakePHP ACL

http://mark-story.com/posts/view/auth-and-acl-an-end-to-end-tutorial-pt-1

http://mark-story.com/posts/view/auth-and-acl-an-end-to-end-tutorial-pt-2

It has a much better explanation.

Comment: I'm a huge fan of CakePHP, but I really do not like that Cake connects controller actions and models so tightly. Model are mostly just repositories, most real life (especially WebMVC) controllers tend to use comlex queries affecting multiple tabels or none (calling web services etc.) Applying that tight coupling to ACL in Cake turns out to make its ACL completely unusable for most apps. When you need ACL in an app, you want to do the following at random places in your logic: $this->Security->isAllowed($actionForPermission, $additionalCredentials, $options).

Comment: Thats not possible to do in Cake and you also can't get a sound architecture if your access control points are bound to actions. Mostly I turned to have written an ACL myself.

Comment: Mark Story is one of the CakePHP developers. I really doubt that he wrote something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you may want to check out a plugin called [Permissionable](https://github.com/jmcneese/permissionable) since it has the concepts of groups. It has a bit of a learning curve to grasp the concepts behind it but if you're familiar with UNIX permissions, that will help.

[Here](http://jmcneese.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/rmac-ftw-part-1/) is a good explanation on it.